# gae error:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user_is_member'

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
class Thread(db.Model):
  members = db.StringListProperty()

  def user_is_member(self, user):
    return str(user) in self.members
```

and

```
thread = Thread.get(db.Key.from_path('Thread', int(id)))
is_member = thread.user_is_member(user)
```

but the error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 511, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\util.py", line 62, in check_login
    handler_method(self, *args)
  File "D:\zjm_code\forum_blog_gae\main.py", line 222, in get
    is_member = thread.user_is_member(user)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user_is_member'
```

why ?

thanks

Comment: Looks like db.Key.from_path('Thread', int(id)) does not create a valid key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're attempting to fetch an entity by key, but no entity with that key exists, so .get() is returning None. You need to check that a valid entity was returned before trying to act on it, like this:

```
thread = Thread.get(db.Key.from_path('Thread', int(id)))
if thread:
  is_member = thread.user_is_member(user)
else:
  is_member = False
```

or, equivalently:

```
thread = Thread.get(db.Key.from_path('Thread', int(id)))
is_member = thread.user_is_member(user) if thread else False
```

Comment: @Thomas: No, because that will return None (instead of False) if thread is None.