# Python GAE datastoreAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python, google-app-engine, syntax-error, google-cloud-datastore

Running the code bellow, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CG\Documents\ud\contract\main.py", line 81, in get
    numBook = contract.book_number
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'book_number'
```

Since I'm putting this initial row in the bd Contract (as sugested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787319/gae-errorattributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-user-is-member) and others similar questions):

```
first_query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Contract ORDER BY date DESC")
                if first_query is None: # Puting something in db if it's empty
                    first_record = Contract(book_number = 1, initial_page = 1, final_page = 1)
                    first_record.put()
```

I also make a test to verify if the query is returning none:

```
first_query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Contract ORDER BY date DESC")
    if first_query is None: # Puting something in db if it's empty
        first_record = Contract(book_number = 1, initial_page = 1, final_page = 1)
        first_record.put()
    else:         
        numBook = 0
        numInitialPage = 0
        numFinalPage = 0
```

When I print this:
    q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Contract ORDER BY date DESC")

I get this:

When I print this:

```
contract = q.get()
```

I get **None**

How to fix that making put() work?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright 2007 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

import os

import webapp2

import jinja2

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

import re

from google.appengine.ext import db

USER_RE = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{3,20}$")
def valid_person(person):
    return USER_RE.match(person)

PASS_RE = re.compile(r"^.{3,20}$")
def valid_SSN(SSN):
    return PASS_RE.match(SSN)

EMAIL_RE = re.compile(r"^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$")
def valid_email(email):
    return EMAIL_RE.match(email)

import time

import datetime


def dateToday():
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    todayDay = str(today.day)
    todayMonth = str(today.month)
    monthExt = {'1':' January ', '2':'February', '3':' March ', '4':'April', '5':'May', '6':'June', '7':' July ', '8':'August', '9':'September', '10':'October', '11':'November ', '12':'December'}
    todayYear = str(today.year)
    return(todayDay + ' of  ' + monthExt[todayMonth] + ' of ' + todayYear)

class Contract(db.Model):
    book_number = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    initial_page = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    final_page = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        first_query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Contract ORDER BY date DESC")
            if first_query is None: # Puting something in db if it's empty
                first_record = Contract(book_number = 1, initial_page = 1, final_page = 1)
                first_record.put()
        q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Contract ORDER BY date DESC")
        contract = q.get() # return only the first entity
        numBook = contract.book_number
        numInitialPage = contract.initial_page
        numFinalPage = contract.final_page
        template_values = {"person": "",
                                       "nacionality": "",
                                       "SSN": "",
                                       "driverLicense": "",
                                       "email":"",
                                       "person_error": "",
                                       "SSN_error": "",
                                       "driverLicense_error": "",
                                       "address": "",
                                       "email_error": "",
                                       "numBook": numBook,
                                       "numInitialPage": numInitialPage,
                                       "numFinalPage": numFinalPage,
                                       }
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

    def post(self):
        person_name = self.request.get("person")
        user_nacionality = self.request.get('nacionality')
        user_profession = self.request.get('profession')
        user_maritalStatus = self.request.get('maritalStatus')
        user_SSN = self.request.get('SSN')
        user_email = self.request.get('email')
        user_driverLicense = self.request.get('driverLicense')
        person_error = ""
        SSN_error = ""
        driverLicense_error = ""
        geted_email_error = ""
        address = self.request.get('address')
        contractType = self.request.get("contractType")
        owner = self.request.get("owner")
        witness = self.request.get("witness")
        numBook = self.request.get("numBook")
        numInitialPage = self.request.get("numInitialPage")
        numFinalPage = self.request.get("numFinalPage")

        if (person_name and valid_person(person_name)) and (user_SSN and valid_SSN(user_SSN)) and ((not user_email) or (user_email and valid_email(user_email))):
            a = Person(firstName = person_name,
                                   nacionality = user_nacionality,
                                   maritalStatus = user_maritalStatus,
                                   profession = user_profession,
                                   SSN = int(user_SSN),
                                   driverLicense = int(user_driverLicense)
                                   #address = user_address
                                   )
            a.put()
            self.redirect('/your_contract?person=%s&nacionality=%s&profession=%s&maritalStatus=%s&SSN=%s&driverLicense=%s&email=%s&witness=%s&owner=%s&contractType=%s&address=%s&numBook=%s&numInitialPage=%s&numFinalPage=%s' % (person_name, user_nacionality, user_profession, user_maritalStatus, user_SSN, user_driverLicense, user_email,
witness, owner, contractType, address, numBook, numInitialPage, numFinalPage))

        else:
            if not person_name or not valid_person(person_name):
                person_error = "Oh no!!! this person name isn't valid!"
            if not user_SSN or not valid_SSN(user_SSN):
                SSN_error = "Oh no!!! SSN isn't valid!"
            if user_email and not valid_email(user_email):
                geted_email_error = "Oh no!!! e-mail isn't valid!"
            template_values = {"person": person_name,
                                "nacionality": user_nacionality,
                                "maritalStatus": user_maritalStatus,
                                "profession": user_profession,
                                "SSN": user_SSN,
                                "driverLicense": user_driverLicense,
                                "email": user_email,
                                "person_error": person_error,
                                "SSN_error": SSN_error,
                                "driverLicense_error": user_driverLicense,
                                "address": address,
                                "email_error": geted_email_error}
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

class your_contractHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        geted_person_name = self.request.get('person')
        geted_user_nacionality = self.request.get("nacionality")
        geted_user_profession = self.request.get("profession")
        geted_user_maritalStatus = self.request.get("maritalStatus")
        geted_user_SSN = self.request.get('SSN')
        geted_user_email = self.request.get('email')
        geted_user_driverLicense = self.request.get('driverLicense')
        geted_person_error = ""
        geted_SSN_error = ""
        geted_driverLicense_error = ""
        geted_address = self.request.get('address')
        geted_owner = self.request.get("owner")
        geted_witness = self.request.get("witness")
        geted_contractType = self.request.get("contractType")
        geted_dateToday = dateToday()
        your_contract = jinja_environment.get_template('your_contract.html')
        geted_numBook = self.request.get('numBook')
        geted_numInitialPage = self.request.get('numInitialPage')
        geted_numFinalPage = self.request.get('numFinalPage')

        contract = Contract(book_number = geted_numBook, initial_page = geted_numInitialPage, final_page = geted_numFinalPage)
        contract.put()

        your_contract_values = {"person":geted_person_name,
                                "nacionality":geted_user_nacionality,
                                "maritalStatus": geted_user_maritalStatus,
                                "profession": geted_user_profession,
                                "SSN":geted_user_SSN,
                                "driverLicense":geted_user_driverLicense,
                                "address":geted_address,
                                "email":geted_user_email,
                                "contractType":geted_contractType,
                                "dateContract":geted_dateToday,
                                "numBook":geted_numBook,
                                "numInitialPage":geted_numInitialPage,
                                "numFinalPage":geted_numInitialPage,
                                }
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(your_contract.render(your_contract_values))


class Contract(db.Model):
    book_number = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    initial_page = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    final_page = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler), ('/your_contract', your_contractHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
first_query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Contract ORDER BY date DESC").get()
```

You have to use **get()** to select the last record (and not the query object). So, the code will run inside the if block.

Answer (score 1):

May be because the query is returning nothing, try this :

```
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Contract ORDER BY date DESC")
contract = q.get() # return only the first entity
if contract is not None:
    numBook = contract.book_number
else:
    print('contract is None')
```

Comment: In addition to checking that you have got a result form the query, have you confirmed that you have any records in the datastore to actually retrieve?

Comment: I made this test (if is None, put something into db) but the error persist: 
first_query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Contract ORDER BY date DESC")
       if first_query is None:
           first_record = Contract(book_number = 1, initial_page = 1, final_page = 1)
          first_record.put()

Comment: but is that code run.  Check via the /admin page and look in the datastore viewer to see if you have records.  Also if you have the check on the q.get() for None and you are still getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'book_number'` then you aren't doing the check correctly.  Update you code here.  As the error says None object has no attribute 'book_number'

Comment: first_query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Contract ORDER BY date DESC")  will return a query object.  You need to read the docs and then you will see the db.GqlQuery creates a query object, you then need to call run(), get() or fetch().  So you add of a record never runs

Comment: I will sound like a broken record here - but you really do need to spend some time reading the docs.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I make a mistake: <google.appengine.ext.db.GqlQuery object at 0x0000000005FFAF98> refers to the query, not to the last record. When I print just the last record I do get **None**. But I don't understand yet why put() doesn't work. Reading the docs now.